# SQLite SELECT record based on Time format "HH:mm:ss"

Tags: sqlite, select

This is my SQLite Database Table :

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| ID | StartTime | EndTime  |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | 07:00:01  | 23:00:00 |
|  2 | 23:00:01  | 07:00:00 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Now I am having problem creating sql query to select them.

- `Time1`='14:00:00'

I used

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' 
WHERE StartTime <= '14:00:00'
AND EndTime >= '14:00:00';
```

Result for selecting `Time1` returned is **correct**, I got what I want.

**But**

- `Time2`='07:00:00'
- `Time3`='06:00:00'

For `Time2` and `Time3`, I can't seems to determine what should be the `SELECT` statement conditions?

**QUESTION**

What should be the algorithm and SQLite statements to handle such situation, i.e. when it's `Time1`, only `ID 1` is returned, when `Time2` and `Time3`, only `ID 2` is returned?

I am using Java to execute SQLite statements, therefore I am not sure if all the functions are supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example query ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/5a4a5/3)):

```
select * from t where 
(
(StartTime<=EndTime) and 
 ('07:00:00' between StartTime and EndTime)
)
 or
(
(StartTime>EndTime) and 
 ( 
    ('07:00:00' between StartTime and '23:59:59')
     or
    ('07:00:00' between '00:00:00' and EndTime)

 )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE HOUR(StartTime) <= HOUR('14:00:00')
AND HOUR(EndTime) >= HOUR('14:00:00');
```

Comment: What about when the time is '06:00:00' or '07:00:00'? I can't seem to get ID '2' using the same sql statement.

Comment: I just edited my question, is it possible to have such statements?

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE StartTime <= TIME_FORMAT("14:00:00","%H:%i:%s") 
AND EndTime >= TIME_FORMAT("14:00:00","%H:%i:%s");
```